# Sheriff Hemlock - Favored Son trait

Tags: pathfinder-1e, adventure-path, traits

I am planning on taking the trait "[Favored Son](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/campaign-traits/rise-of-the-runelords/favored-son-daughter/)" of Sheriff Hemlock in the AP Rise of the Rune Lords. would anyone provide me some feedback how I could use this trait besides the way they say in the trait description.

Comment: This is kinda broad, but it's just one trait - I think this is answerable but it has to be answered with Good Subjective - answerers, we don't want your brainstormed ideas, we want what you actually have done, seen done, or read about being done with this trait in Runelords.  If that means no answers, it means no answers.  Speculative answers will be removed.

Comment: @mxyzplk except the question has no clear goal. Even with Good Subjective answers, the question is still subject to our 'conceivably having a single "best" answer' standard is it not? Which answer out of "you could use it for X", "you could use it for Y", or "you could use it for Z" would actually be the answer to the question when they're all equally (in)valid, even with Good Subjective backup?

Comment: I can't find anywhere on the internet of examples of how people have used this trait. So even if you haven't used it but can offer me suggestions on outside the box methods of using it that would be excellent! :)

Comment: @Atalius -- keep in mind that the Stack form factor is designed for structured Q&A, not open-ended discussion.  You may be better off taking this topic up in a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go?noredirect=1&lq=1) thread. Also, read the [tour], and welcome!

Comment: appreciate it, I will post it in the link you provided, my apologies. You can close this question if you like, sorry for the inconvenience, I was unfamiliar with the link provided by Shalvenay.

Comment: Although in my other thread I posted people are voting to close it, why is that? https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7121/favored-son-campaign-trait-rotrl

Comment: @Atalius -- that's because I linked you to the *list of forums* we keep -- you weren't meant to ask on Meta :P

Comment: @Atalius Are you looking to avoid spoilers? I would tend to think so, but I'm not sure how I could give the kind of answer that mxyzplk describes (i.e., referring to specific instances where the trait was useful or would have been useful) without treading into spoiler territory.